# Is there any other way passing lookup parameters in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, many-to-many

I'm trying to pass a lookup parameter to my views.py to render to the templates

model.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True, unique=True)

class Post(models.Model):

    """"
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    cover = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True )
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='posts', blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def index_category(request, category):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(categories__name__contains=category).order_by('-created_on')
    context = {
        "category": category,
        "posts": posts,
    }
    return render(request, "blog/index_category.html", context)
```

index_category.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
    <h1>{% block title %}{{ category | title }}{% endblock title %}</h1>
    <hr>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <h2><a href="{% url 'index-detail' post.slug %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
        <small>
            {{ post.created_on.date }} |&nbsp;
            Categories:&nbsp;
            {% for category in post.categories.all %}
            <a href="{% url 'blog-category' category.name %}">
                {{ category.name }}
            </a>&nbsp;
            {% endfor %}
        </small>
        <p>{{ post.body | slice:":200" }}...</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

When i refresh my localhost on my category page, it's returning nothing except the block title.

Is there any other way to filter the many-to-many relationship between the post and the category???

Answer (score 0):

To avoid future problems with similar `category` names change this:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(categories__name__contains=category).order_by('-created_on')
```

to relation call: (for which you have `related_name='posts'` in `Post.category` field)

```
category = Category.objects.get(name__iexact=category)
posts = category.posts.all().order_by('-created_on')
```

For more help, show `urls.py`.

How do you pass the `category` variable into the function `index_category`?

Comment: ```urlpatterns = [    path('', views.index, name='blog'),    path("<category>/", views.index_category, name="blog-category"),    path('<str:slug>', views.index_details, name = 'blog-detail'),    ] ```

Comment: `urls` looks fine. I've edited my answer, maybe that approach will help. You have to use full category name in url. Also you have added some related objects in db, right?